# Silverlight: Use a collection for multiple options in a Data Form?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dataform

I have a data form that is working pretty well. One of the properties of my data object is an `ObservableCollection`. Right now, in the data form, it only displays the `ToString()` of the colletion. Not very helpful.

I'd like some sort of autocomplete box with valid options, and when the user selects them they will be added to the data object's collection. (I discussed doing that in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688613/user-friendly-way-to-enter-a-list-in-silverlight-4), but it's not using data forms.)

Is there a way to do this, while using the rest of the controls automatically generated by the data form? I'd rather not specify everything myself, just to get this one control.

I'd also like to override a normal text input box for a field to make it an autocomplete box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to a public property of the object in the collection.